# XML import to access DB import only one child data Even if it has three

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have xml structure like this

```
   <Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>ABC</OrderNo>
        <ItemDetails>
            <Name>Shirt</Name>
            <Name>Socks</Name>
            <ItemPrice>30</ItemPrice>
            <ItemPrice>40</ItemPrice>
        </ItemDetails>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

Like this i have 1000 orders in xml's . So when i try to import these data into the access Db 2010 im getting only one item price& Name  record in the item details table .

How to overcome this

Answer (score 3):

Your XML needs to be organized differently to do this. Right now the XML is written as though there are two `Name` and two `ItemPrice` columns in your `Item Details` table and what ends up happening is it will put the first `name` it sees into one record, then the first `itemPrice` then there are no more detail records so everything else is ignored.

You're XML should look more like this. I.e. you need to make some association between the name and the price and that is done at the `ItemDetail` level.

```
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderNo>ABC</OrderNo>
        <ItemDetails>
            <ItemDetail>
                <Name>Shirt</Name>
                <ItemPrice>30</ItemPrice>
            </ItemDetail>
            <ItemDetail>
                <Name>Socks</Name>
                <ItemPrice>40</ItemPrice>
            </ItemDetail>
        </ItemDetails>
    </Order>
</Orders>
```

Comment: Yes that will be good. Organising now will be a big task it is driven to the halfway . Just want to know is there any way we can achieve this

Comment: @saikri I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you asking how you can generate your xml differently?